# Django rest framework retrieving lists in serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Take the following example into account.  I have two models, one `Author` and one `Article`.  They look like so:

```
# author.py

from django.db import models


class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

```
# article.py

from django.db import models
from authors.models import Author


class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

My serializers look like so:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Article
from authors.serializers import AuthorSerializer


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Author

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now, if I wish to get articles from my API, that's simple.  Getting articles attaches the author and that's all well and good -- but how do I get the inverse?  For instance, if I want to get authors with the latest 5 articles that they have written?  So the intended output would be something like:

```
{
    "first_name": "Sethen",
    "last_name": "Maleno",
    "articles": [
      {
          "text": "some article"
      },
      {
          "text": "another article"
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ArticleWithoutAuthorSerializer(ArticleSerializer):
    # Prevent author field serialization and endless nesting
    author = None

class AuthorSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    articles = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_articles(self, author):
        # Five recently posted articles
        articles = author.article_set.order_by('-published')[:5]
        return ArticleWithoutAuthorSerializer(articles, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Author
```

Comment: I see... Is there no DRF fancy way to do this?

Comment: No, nothing like that.  You can forget the `recently published` bit, that was just an example.  What I am trying to do is understand more of the basics and nested relationships with DRF.  This example may be overly simple.